# I have a problem with two .js files in a react app! I am using the react-router-dom. My problem is with the Link tag

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm making a static web app with React. It has more pages so I'm using the react-router-dom, but when i use the Link tag it shows up not just on the page I want it on but also on the page it's suppose to redirect.
Except for that everything works just fine: the page it's pointing at is rendering just fine, but with the link in the bottom left corner. Can anyone look over my code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

I only want the link 'To Do List' to show up here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Todo from '../apps/todo/Todo'

class Projects extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/todo" component={Todo} />
          <Link style={projectsTodo} href="/todo">
            To Do List
          </Link>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

The link shows up here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Header from './layout/Header'
import Todos from './Todos'
import uuid from 'uuid'

class Todo extends Component {
  state = {
    todos: [
      {
        id: uuid.v4(),
        title: 'Learn React',
        completed: false,
      },
      {
        id: uuid.v4(),
        title: 'Find suitable web hosting service',
        completed: false,
      },
    ],
  }

  delTodo = id => {
    this.setState({
      todos: [...this.state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id)],
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Todos todos={this.state.todos} delTodo={this.delTodo} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Todo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are rendering the Link without any specified route (so it is rendered on all routes). See the [first example of React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) to get a better understanding.

If you don't want this to happen, then define another component `Home` (for example) that will hold the Link and add another Route to your Router that will render that component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Todo from '../apps/todo/Todo'

const Home = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <Link style={projectsTodo} href="/todo">
        To Do List
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
}

class Projects extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/todo" component={Todo} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```